# Date Only Attribute in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, date, datetime, json.net, .net-core-3.1

I am migrating a C# API from .NET Framework to .NET Core 3.1.

I have a requirement that some fields return `yyyyMMdd` only (no time)
and other fields that would return the full DateTime Value (Date and Time).

In the old .NET Framework world, we could make a quick converter like this:

```
public class OnlyDateConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public OnlyDateConverter()
    {
        DateTimeFormat = "yyyyMMdd";
    }
}
```

and use it in my model like

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(DateTimeConverter))]
public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
```

That isn't working in .NET Core 3.1.

When I call it via Swagger, my JSON that is returned is:

`"OrderDate": "2002-05-22T00:00:00"`

I know you can add a `JsonSerializerOption` in `Startup.cs`, however that will force all dates to use the same formatting. I need to pick and choose.

I have tried:

- making multiple json converters, however they never get called/work
- `[DataType(DataType.Date)]`
- `[JsonConverter(typeof(DateTimeConverter))]`

I have spent all day on this. I'm hoping someone has done this and can point out my silly mistake.

Answer (score 4):

This code work for me

in your output model add this :

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonDateConverterExtension))]
public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

where JsonDateConverterExtension is :

```
public class JsonDateConverterExtension : JsonConverter<DateTime?>
{
    public override DateTime? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) 

       => DateTime.ParseExact(reader.GetString(),
              "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime? value, JsonSerializerOptions options)

     => writer.WriteStringValue(value?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```